# Error in regular expression and transform into float?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I´m trying to obtain a string inside a file

```
id = re.compile('[1-90]\s[0-59].[0-99].+')
if id.search(pal):
    print ('si')
    a = id.search(pal)
else:
    print('NO')
```

---

```
>>>a.group()
'7 3.99 N,  1 13.02 W'
```

But the original string is :  37 3.99 N,  1 13.02 W

Then I´ve lost the first str '3'

How can I modify the pattern in order to obtain the full string

Another question
Haw can I use the string as a digit, ie, this is a position in Degrees and Minutes and I ´d like to transform.... into  degrees.minutes gg.mmm

Comment: Note that `[1-90]` and friends is actually saying, any number between 1 and 9 as well as 0, not any number between 1 and 90.

Comment: Same thing for [0-59]; it's saying "Any number between 0 and 5, as well as 9, but not the others"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture these one character at a time.  For instance, the following regex will capture the first half of your string (assuming no more than two digits are allowed in the leading numbers.)

```
`[1-9]?[0-9]\s[0-9]\.[0-9]{2}\s[NS],`
```

This regex matches up to (and including) your comma. The `?` indicates that the leading digit is optional. Escaping the period with a `\` makes it match a literal period instead of any one character.  The `{2}` means to match exactly two instances of what preceded it.  But you really ought to checkout [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/) and [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) for more regular expression help.

Answer (score 1):

> Then I´ve lost the first str '3' How can I modify the pattern in order to obtain the full string

You forget to add `+` in first group of `[1-90]`

```
[1-90]+\s[0-59].[0-99].+
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dT4cG6/1)

`[1-90]` and `[0-99]` means digits 1 to 9

---

If you are looking to check numbers in a range then try in this way.

Check range from 1 to 90

```
^([1-9]|[1-8][0-9]|90)$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eA2dW9/5)

Comment: I think the OP has more severe issues than you're addressing.  Those periods work because they are wildcards, not because they're explicitly matching literal periods, which is what he needs.  In short, this regex is too permissive.